# Angular - Parse request header on application startup

Tags: angular

I have 3 Domain names hosted with Godaddy, They all point at the same server hosting my angular 2 app, Is there a way to check the header of the request to determine which of the 3 domains the user is coming from?

Comment: by `header` what you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is out when your Angular application is starting. So you can't parse your headers here.

I suggest you to prefer a request param that you add in your Godaddy hosted apps request, and then parse it in an Angular component with `@angular/router` like this :

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, OnDestroy, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let origin= params['origin'];
        console.log(origin);
      });
  }

}
```

Alternatively, you could parse the request param with a pure Javascript on page loading (`location.search`...).

If you cannot edit the Godaddy hosted apps requests, you will have to configure a reverse proxy on the server which serve your Angular app.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thank you Karbos!